# Mikrotik - Filter rule is accepted, but dst-nat not working

Tags: firewall, nat, mikrotik-routeros

I have an NAT issue with mikrotik CCR1016-12G - namely I can't see any packets going to my dst-nat rules and dst-nat rules are not working.

I have tried disabling filtering rules that might drop any packets, and I've also tried to make a specific rule to accept a specific port with no luck:

```
chain=input action=accept connection-state=new protocol=tcp 
src-address=0.0.0.0/0 in-interface=ether01-gateway dst-port=8088
```

I can see the packets coming in to the filter rules and assume that they get accepted(as I have the previous rule in place), but no packets are going to the dst-nat part:

```
chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.1.88 to-ports=80 
protocol=tcp src-address=0.0.0.0 dst-address="Outer-IP" dst port=8088
```

What could be the issue that I don't see any packets going to NAT?

Answer (score 1):

In the dst-nat rule:

```
src-address=0.0.0.0
```

I think it means exactly the ip address `0.0.0.0`. (same as `0.0.0.0/32`)

Change it to `0.0.0.0/0` . It means every ip address.

Or just remove the `src-address=0.0.0.0` from the rule